# File name as variable

Tags: php

I had a problem while executing below code on my localhost server, I am trying to get counter from text file named as "count.txt" and I want to save somethings to variable text files as 0.txt, 1.txt etc.

But everytime I am getting 1 in count.txt, irrespective of whatever in count.txt already. And second thing it's not genrating varibale text files as 1.txt, 2.txt etc. I can't figure out what's the error and I m eager to know, before that I should let you know that  I have set permison on that folder by using `chmod 777`.

```
<?php
$filc = fopen("count.txt", "w+") or die ("can't open file");
$stor = "";
while (!feof($filc))
{
  $stor=$stor.fgetc($filc);
}
$stor_file = $stor.".txt";
/*stor_file is ready!!!*/
$stor_num = (int)$stor;
$stor_num++;
$filn = fopen($stor_file, "w+") or die("unable to make 2nd file");
$thing = $_GET["name"];
fwrite($filn, $thing);
fwrite($filc, $stor_num);
fclose($filn);
fclose($filc);
?>
```

Comment: make sure you don't have a newline at the end of the file, or `$stor` will be `\n` after your while loop and cast it to `0`, which when you incremeent will always be 1

Comment: Why are you trying to read from a file you just truncated?

Comment: So what's the solution Populus?

Comment: @symcbean "+w" will create file if it does'nt exist.
[http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_file.asp]

Comment: @peeyushrj: "'w+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and **truncate the file to zero length**" - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: @symcbean True So. SO I think I need to change '+w' -> '+x' ?

Comment: @symcbean Yeah! It's working now. I got the Idea, thanx. Next time I'll read bit more carefully.